# Datatable persistance when bound to a combobox or datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a datatable with global scope bound to a combobox. 
in my view model I use notifyoroperty change to return the row index.
But when I try to use the index to retreive the datafrom the datatable the table is empty.

Model

```
  private string _Store;
        public string Store
        {
            get { return _Store; }
            set { _Store = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Store");
            }
        }

        private string _Account;
        public string Account
        {
            get { return _Account; }
            set
            {
                _Account = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Account");
            }
        }
```

ViewModel

```
public DataTable customerDataTable = new DataTable(); 
customerDataTable = ds.Tables[1];

 _Customer.Store = "arlans";
_Customer.Account = "555";
```

xaml

```
<ComboBox Name="storeNameCB" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding customerDataTable.StoreName}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" Margin="0 5 0 0" Grid.Column="3" Height="30" FontSize="15" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

I was able to return the index value for the combobox selection
but error seems to be that the customerDataTable is no longer filled with data.

```
_Customer.Store = customerDataTable.Rows[indx][2].ToString();
_Customer.Account = customerDataTable.Rows[indx][1].ToString();
```

Comment: DisplayMemberPath binding is very unusual. Please be more specific about the structure of your data and what's the DataContext

Comment: Also `customerDataTable` is a field, but needs to be a property in order to participate in any kind of binding.

Comment: public MainWindow()
        {

            ViewModels.CustomerViewModel db = new CustomerViewModel();
            db.LdDataTables();
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new CustomerViewModel();
            dtGrid.ItemsSource = db.prpDataTable.DefaultView;
            storeNameCB.ItemsSource = db.customerDataTable.DefaultView;
            storeNameCB.DisplayMemberPath = "StoreName";
        }

Comment: Generally, please [edit] your Question instead of writing code in comments. Regarding your code: Why do you create two different `CustomerViewModel` there? Why do you set DisplayMemberPath both in constructor and in XAML binding?

Comment: I was able to populate a combobox with my list of customers (customerDataTable) then was able to return the index value of  my selection in the combobox. I was thinking that I could use the index value to retreive the dat from the customerDataTable but  shows up as null or empty.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had not noticed the 2nd viewmodel. Deleted it and it corrected the issue I was having..

Comment: Ok, voting to close since your problem is solved and the necessary information is not included in the question.